# items don't appear directly in the action bar as action buttons

Tags: android, android-activity

I have followed the tutorail http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html for creating an action bar with items apear directly in the action bar as action buttons. yet my items don't appear as buttons.. this is how it looks like: (the items: delete, edit,add)
any idea why?

[image]

my device is galaxy s4

this is my code:

activity:

```
public class SingleTask extends ActionBarActivity{ 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_task);

    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar(); 

     actionbar.show();
     //some more things .....

 }
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.task_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }               
}
```

task_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_remove"
      android:orderInCategory="101"
      android:title="@string/action_delete"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_edit"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
      android:title="@string/action_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item android:id="@+id/create_new"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
      android:title="@string/action_add"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

menifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.getset"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="shiransarusi.com.getset.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransarusi.com.login.StudentLogIn"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_log_in" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransarusi.com.getset.StudentMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_menu" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransarusi.com.login.StudentRegister"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransarusi.com.getset.JSONParser"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_student_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransarusi.com.getset.imageAdapter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image_adapter" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransaruci.com.tasks.AllTasksActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_all_tasks" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransaruci.com.tasks.EditTaskActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_task" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransaruci.com.tasks.NewTaskActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_task" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="shiransaruci.com.tasks.SingleTask"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_single_task" >
    </activity>
  </application>    
  <!--   Internet Permissions -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 </manifest>
```

Comment: try `android:showAsAction="always"` instead of `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: I tried that.. it didn't help..

Comment: I doubt android namespace included in menu file. Reason is you are using support library. Can you just include `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` inside `<menu>` tag of in menu.xml file?

Comment: I tried that..<menu  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:appName="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"> still don't work.. just xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" will not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: [menu-resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

You can try:

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

OR

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```